# Typescript doesn't have a function type?

Tags: typescript

I need to clone an already existing javascript code into Typescript. The javascript is :

```
object.getsomething( function(err, result) {
    // async
});
```

How can I type the parameter `function(err,result)` ?

I tried `retrieve(func: function(err:string, result:string) : any){}`

but the my intellisense says "err" and "result" name can't be found. And I can't find any documentation about the "function" type.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "fat arrow" notation as follows:

```
retrieve(func: (err: string, result: string) => any) { ... }
```

Comment: upvoting this correct answer, although the question is probably a duplicate.